# How to Format Rbind/Cbind in the Same Dataset/ Loop?

Tags: r, dataframe

How do i order my columns from ascending to descending order? I only have 1 row so its essnetially saying, how do I order my rows from ascending to descending order then delete the smallest ones?

Also, if I'm trying to display data, is there a way to do rbind and cbind in the same command?

For example, my data is 5 cars, with different mileages, safety etc. I would like so the format to be:

```
                                   car 1                       car 2          
   Average Mileage
   Average Safety
```

my current function uses rbind but displays the data so that it's like

```
 Mileage
 car1
 car2
 car3
```

How do I do it to make my safety appear in the next column? If i use cbind, it erases what I currently have.

Comment: It is not clear from the output.  Can you show few lines of input dataset

Comment: @yearofwisdom I don't understand why you deleted an answered question.  I meant `Sort Row/Columns in R`.  It may be useful for somebody who come across with the same problem.

Comment: The question's unclear: *"I only have 1 row... how do I order my rows from ascending to descending order then delete the smallest ones?"* I think you mean *"I have multiple rows, I want to order them by <variable> then only keep one row (i.e keep the max)"*

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you mean by ascending to descending.

You can order a column of integers in an ascending manner like so:

```
my.dataframe <- sort(my.dataframe$my.column)
```

Comment: If you want them decreasing, then `sort(my.dataframe$my.column,decreasing=TRUE)`. I agree with @Chuck that the way you asked the question is rather obscure...